# Checking if a variable contains a memory address

Tags: objective-c, ios7

My game has a method that receives a string. Since iOS7, it begun crashing sometimes in it.

In the method, I call `lowercaseString` on that string, and then it crashes with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

```
-(void)changeDirection:(NSString *)_direction {
    if (![[direction lowercaseString] isEqualToString:[_direction lowercaseString]]) {

    }
}
```

Something that I noticed was that these times this string seems to be a **memory address**:

[image]

Which explains why is it crashing - I'm calling `lowercaseString` on a memory address.

Right now, the most logical solution would be to see why is this method receiving a memory address instead of an actual string, I guess.

However, for now, I want to make a quick workaround, which leads to this question:

How can I detect whether the given parameter is an actual string object like `@"Hello"`
 or a memory address?

Comment: Might be an already released NSString

Comment: In Objective-C all objects are passed by their memory address, so there is no such thing as detecting when a parameter is a string object or a memory address. Most likely `_direction` has either not been initialized, or was assigned to, but the object it pointed to was deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects live on the heap, what you are calling `NSString` is actually a pointer to it. And a pointer is a memory address, so that's expected behavior not a issue.

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` means that you are accessing the memory in a bad way, i.e. the memory address you are pointing to is not valid memory.

This can happen when you try to access a dangling pointer (i.e. a pointer to an object that was already released) or an uninitialized pointer.

The error is not in the code you posted, but rather in the code that produces the `_direction` argument to that method.

Comment: How can I tell if whatever lies in _direction has been initialized or not, though? (Besides having the application crash lol)

Comment: You cannot detect a dangling or an uninitialized pointer. You have to go through the code and see whether there's a path that leads to a wrong behavior. The static analyzer helps a lot in this cases. Also, are you using ARC?

Comment: I'm not using ARC. Thank you though!

Comment: Well then save yourself a few headaches and start using it.

Comment: Even with ARC, it's still good to know about how Obj-C memory management works behind the scenes. Also, there's still a lot of non-ARC code out there you may need to be able to read and modify. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224091/basic-memory-management-in-objective-c-ios